# How to implement AsyncListener/ReadListener/WriteListener.onError in an async servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

The [Servlet 3.1 API](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf) defines an asynchronous servlet API which goes down to implementing the interfaces AsyncListener, WriteListener and ReadListener. All these have an onError callback, but I cannot find any useful information about the error conditions and expected behavior for this callback.

In an [example](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/swchan2/archive/2013/04/16/non-blocking-io-servlet-31-example) the author completes the AsyncContext in the onError callbacks:

```
public void onError(final Throwable t) {
    ac.complete();
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there any best practice on what the async servlet should do in case of an error?

Interestingly, the onError handlers are not called if the HTTP request is aborted by the client (tested with Jetty 9.1.3). However, in that case, there seems to be a memory leak here, since the WriteListener seems not to be cleaned up. Only the ReadListener and AsyncListener instances see a finalize() call when System.gc() is called (for testing).